# Comma format error (siunitx)

Tags: siunitx

[image]

Why is the comma missing in the rendering of `1,089` ?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-ignore={,},input-decimal-markers={.},group-separator={,}}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% for the vertical padding
\begin{tabular}{|cc
|
S[table-format=3.0]
S[table-format=5.0]
|
S[table-format=6.0]
|
}
\hline
& &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{suffers from X} & \\
& &    {yes} & {no} & {total} \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{test + for X}
     & yes &  90  & 999  & 1,089 \\
     & no  &  10  & 98,901 & 98,911 \\
\hline
 & total & 100  & 99,900  & 100,000 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `input-ignore={,},input-decimal-markers={.}`

Comment: Seems the group separator is included for numbers greater than 9999.

Comment: @Johannes_B That may indeed be the issue - but I think it makes the column harder to read. Is there a workaround other than ignoring siunitx, right justifying the column? (Your first comment isn't a fix.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default for `group-minimum-digits` is 5, the integer 1089 has 4 digits only.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  input-ignore={,},
  input-decimal-markers={.},
  group-separator={,},
  group-minimum-digits=4,
}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% for the vertical padding
\begin{tabular}{|cc
|
S[table-format=3.0]
S[table-format=5.0]
|
S[table-format=6.0]
|
}
\hline
& &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{suffers from X} & \\
& &    {yes} & {no} & {total} \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{test + for X}
     & yes &  90  & 999  & 1,089 \\
     & no  &  10  & 98,901 & 98,911 \\
\hline
 & total & 100  & 99,900  & 100,000 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}% remove unwanted space by line end
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Seems like a curious value for the default? Would anyone know why? cc: @JosephWright

Comment: @Brent.Longborough, see ["How the world separates its digits"](http://www.statisticalconsultants.co.nz/blog/how-the-world-separates-its-digits.html)

Comment: Thank you; all I can say is "true, but strange". :)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Nevermind, I deleted my comment. It was indeed very confusing.